# Pig pass tab (\t) as param for dynamic CSV parsing

Tags: java, python, hadoop, apache-pig

I am working on parsing data files with any delimiter data in File (CSV','  TSV '\t'  ';')
the approach works with ',' and ';' but not with tab '\t', how can we pass tab as param to pig?

python code

```
delimiter = '\t'
cmd = 'pig -f sample.pig -p file='+data_file +' -p delimiter=' + delimiter
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Pig

```
-- REGISTER 'piggybank.jar'
-- may use CSVExcelStorage in future
results = LOAD '$file' USING PigStorage('$delimiter');
```

I am getting following exception

```
2014-03-31 03:26:41,412 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.parameters.ParameterSubstitutionPreprocessor - The parameter: "delimiter= " cannot be parsed by Pig. Please double check it
2014-03-31 03:26:41,412 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.parameters.ParameterSubstitutionPreprocessor - Parser give the follow error message:
2014-03-31 03:26:41,413 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.parameters.ParameterSubstitutionPreprocessor - Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 16.
Was expecting one of:
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <OTHER> ...
    <LITERAL> ...
    <SHELLCMD> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a shell here; tab is whitespace to the shell and not sent on as an argument:

```
cmd = ['pig', '-f', 'sample.pig', '-p', 'file=' + data_file, '-p',
       'delimiter=' + delimiter]
subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Note that I am leaving `shell` to the default `False` here; there is no need to pass this command to the shell when you can just invoke `pig` directly. With `shell` left to `False`, pass in an argument list in instead.

Even still, I *think* you may have to give `pig` the sequence `\t` (two characters):

```
delimiter = '\\t'
```

or using a raw string:

```
delimiter = r'\t'
```

If that doesn't work you'll have to resort to special-casing; I only read the [pig latin expressions reference](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#Expressions), so this is untested, but I'd then use a conditional expression and `TAB` as the command-line parameter:

```
results = LOAD '$file' USING PigStorage('$delimiter' == 'TAB' ? '\t' : '$delimiter');
```

And in Python:

```
delimiter = 'TAB'
```

Comment: getting following error, "delimiter=   " cannot be parsed by Pig. Please double check it

Comment: Then the raw tab cannot be passed in like that. Does the `\\t` two-character sequence work?

Comment: nope, others just simply do not parse any of the record

Comment: Hrmz; added a different avenue then with a pig latin conditional expression.